# let $X$ be a topological and A be a nonempty subset of X.then choose the correct statement

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$    be  a topological space  and A  be  a  nonempty  subset of  X. Then
choose the correct statement:

$1.$ $A$  is  dense in   $X$,  if  $(X\setminus A)$  is nowhere  dense in  $X.$

$2.$ $(X\setminus A)$  is nowhere dense , if $A$  is  dense  in  $X.$

$3$.$A$ is dense in  $X$, if the interior of $(X\setminus A)$  is  empty.

$4.$The  interior  of  $(X \setminus A)$  is empty , if $A$  is  dense in  $X$.

## My attempt :  my answer is option $1 ,2 $ and $ 4.$

Option $1$ is True.  Take  $A = \mathbb{Q}.$

Option $2$ is true. Same  logic  in option $1.$

Option $3$ is false.  Take $A =[0,1]$ , $A^0 =A \ \text{interior} =(0,1) \neq \phi.$

Option $4$  is true. Take $A= \mathbb{Q}.$

Is  its correct or not ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated.

thanks u

Comment: what is $\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Thomas complement of $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: If you say true, an example is not an argument. Only for false statements you need to exhibit a counterexample.

Comment: For 3 your example does not obey that the interior of the complement is empty. So it's irrelevant.

Comment: My edit was for a missing word ("space") and for punctuation and formatting only.... BTW \Bbb  is an exact duplicate of \mathbb  and when applying either of them to a single key-stroke character you don't need brace brackets. E.g. \Bbb Q gives $\Bbb Q.$

Comment: The counter-examples to 1. and 2.  in the answers are examples of a set $A$ that is called "dense & co-dense" . I.e., both $A$ and $X$ \ $A$ are dense in $X.$

Comment: okkss @DanielWainfleet..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If $X\setminus A$ is nowhere dense, this means that $X\setminus (X \setminus A)) = A$ contains a dense and open subset, so indeed $A$ is dense. An example cannot answer this, you need an argument.
2. If $A$ is dense, then $X\setminus A$ need not be nowhere dense, as shown by the example $A = \mathbb{Q}$.
3. If the interior of $X\setminus A$ is empty, then $A$ is dense: $\overline{A} = X\setminus \operatorname{int}(X\setminus A))$.
4. If $A$ is dense in $X$, the interior of $X \setminus A$ is empty; this follows by the same formula, or note that otherwise a non-empty interior of $X\setminus A$ could not intersect the dense set $A$.

Comment: The Association Of Pedants deducts marks from both you and the proposer for not specifying in  2. that $X=\Bbb R$ (with the usual topology)............... +1

Answer (score 2):

1) is false, $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Q}'$ which is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. 2) is a reformulation of 1 so is false. 3) is true. think of 4 ;)